# Какие интересные сервисы по унфицированому процессу вы можете посоветовать?

Tags: проектирование, архитектура, uml

Всем привет. Читаю книгу Крэг Ларман "Применение UML и шаблонов проектирования" и кажется все довольно понятно, но очень трудно сохранить в голове все детали. Мне нужна какfz-то всеобъемлющая шпаргалка что-ли. Вообще было бы классно получить ссылку на сервис или программу для проектирования приложений по UP. В общем, буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: не знаю это ли вам нужно, но посмотрите на `Rational Rose`

Comment: @jojo97, скажу Вам ("по секрету"). На самом деле все эти штучки нужны манагерам *нижнего* звена для подготовки **красивых** материалов, которыми манагеры *среднего* звена выбивают финансирование у боссов.

Реальное проектирование систем ничего сложнее текстового редактора, карандашей и пачки бумаги не требует. Ну, еще уютная курилка (или ближайшая кафешка) не мешает.

Comment: @avp, возможно вы правы, если есть с кем обсудить и спроектировать эту систему и к тому же, если у человека больше опыта. Но поскольку я программист одинокий и неопытный, мне совсем не помешает унифицированный процесс.

Comment: @avp, я извиняюсь, но смотрю я на количество Ваших очков и меня слегка изумляет Ваш ответ. Я не хочу Вас никак обидеть, но скажите, пожалуйста, какого размера системы Вы проектировали таким образом? Только, пожалуйста, не надо "достаточно большие", скажите в количестве классов в системе, это какой-никакой, но все же показатель. По крайней мере в Вас я не сомневаюсь, что там не были классы на один метод или наоборот на 100 методов:). Думаю, со связанностью и связностью там все в порядке было. Мне это нужно для собственных выводов, не чтоб Вас задеть как-то. Спасибо.

Comment: @hdimon, я в основном на Си пищу, поэтому классов там нет. Из тех систем, что под рукой одна довольно большая.

--

SMTP gateway между *несвязанными* (в смысле сетевых протоколов) IP  сетями (реализован через общий диск) с фильтрацией почты, ее статистикой и т.п.

Для маршрутизации сообщений используются sendmail, dns, ldap.

Наши исходники в 17 оглавлениях (116 .c, 32 .h и 54 shell) всего 40465 строк. Средний размер .c - 305, .h - 63, shell - 48 строк (такая вот статистика).

Из них собирается 16 загрузочных модулей, 5 из которых постоянно взаимодействуют при передаче почтового сообщения.

Comment: А,понял наверно. 
Просто в книге,по какой меня учат UPу,написано,что это ОО-анализ.К тому же мы честно оговариваем,что это реально полезно при системах в несколько сотен и тысяч классов.Может дело в этом.На небольшие системы,убедился на собственном опыте,действительно нет смысла выполнять все ступени UPа.А для не ОО-языка наверно UP в принципе не получится применить.Просто Вы очень сильно обобщили,сказав,что все это ерунда,чем немного устроили мне когнитивный диссонанс:).А так,все встает на свои места.Отчасти Вы правы.Тем более системы на тысячи классов не каждому из нас придется создавать.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @avp с одной небольшой правкой: UML/RUP иже с ними это средство форматирования мозгов начинающих кодеров. У старых бойцов мозги уже отформатированы как надо - так что им этот UML фтопку.

Comment: @Barmaley Эх, познакомить бы Вас с преподавателем моим из университета, наверно, интересный бы получился разговор:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я рисую прогой yEd Graph Editor . Довольно простая, но при этом все в ней для "рисования" есть.

Comment: Ну этот ответ не сильно относится к моему вопросу.

Comment: "или программу для проектирования приложений по UP". Был вопрос, был ответ:). Если же Вам нужно программу, в которой можно весь цикл разработки сотворить, то по-моему это платные продукты. Если же найдете бесплатное, мне самому очень интересно будет.

Comment: Вот, я говорю про весь цикл. Если знаете платные программы, то поделитесь, возможно, я захочу демку заюзать.

Comment: Гляньте Rational Rose, может это то самое. А вообще, если я по запросу rational unified process через несколько минут нашел хотя бы это, неужели Вы ничего не нашли, добавляя сюда вопрос:).

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не нашел. Про Rational rose слышал, но тут тоже, врядли, то что надо.

Comment: Можете посмотреть на весь IBM-овский пакет [Rational Software](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Software). Если это вам не подойдет, то, пожалуй. ничего не подойдет.